Autohotkey V2 - Date Hotstring Auto-replace
Desired outcome:
Type "cdt" -> Autofills date and time in this format: "Saturday 11:18 AM - Aug 03, 2024"
Current Script:
::cdt::
{
Send FormatTime, ("A_DDD, HH:mm, - A_MMM A_DD, A_YYYY")
}
Please Advise. Thank you :)

Solved.
Autohotkey manual:

"If Format contains date and time elements together, they must not be intermixed. In other words, the string should be dividable into two
halves: a time half and a date half.
For example, a format string
consisting of "hh yyyy mm" would not produce the expected result
because it has a date element in between two time elements."

Solution script:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

::cdt::{ 
Send FormatTime(," @ hh:mm tt ddd - MMM dd, yyy")
}

Returns:  "@ 01:02 PM Sat - Aug 03, 2024"
